# Macのターミナルでどのパスからでも指定のJavaプログラムを実行できるようにしたい

Tags: java, macos

Macを使っており、ターミナルでの挙動に関する質問です。

現在下記を見てlombokをインストールし、delombokをできるようにしました。
https://blog.y-yuki.net/entry/2016/11/15/000000

ただ

```
java -jar lombok.jar delombok -f pretty src -d delombok-src
```

とするときはlombok.jarの配置しているパスで実行しなければならず、めんどくさいです。

どのパスからでもlombok.jarのコマンドが実行できるようにしたいのですが、どうすればいいでしょうか？
javaコマンドのように。

/usr/binの配下に置こうとしましたが、GUIでコピー&ペーストすることができなかったです。
パスを通すのかとも思いましたが、そのやり方でいいのか、またlombok.jarをどこに配置してどのようなコマンドを設定するかといった具体的なところで引っ掛かり、正当なやり方を知りたいと思いました。

わかる方がいらっしゃればよろしくお願いいたします。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`lombok.jar`をパスから指定すれば同じディレクトリに置いておく必要はなくなります。例えば:

```
java -jar <lombok.jarを絶対パスで指定> delombok -f pretty src -d delombok-src
```

---

シェルのalias機能を使えばタイプ数を減らせます。

```
alias delombok='java -jar <lombok.jarを絶対パスで指定> -f pretty'
```

を`~/.bash_profile`なり`~/.zshrc`なり利用されているシェルの設定ファイルに書いておけば、

```
delombok src -d delombok-src
```

で冒頭のコマンドと同じ結果が得られます。

---

`lombok.jar`の置き場所は、 `~/opt/lombok/` ディレクトリとか、わかりやすい名前のディレクトリをホーム下に作れば良いのでは無いでしょうか。
実行可能ファイルではないので `/usr/bin` などに置くのは違和感があります。

Comment: ありがとうございます！

Answer (score 2):

今回のようにJavaプログラムを実行する場合は、追加の引数として **`-classpath`** (省略形は `-cp`) で lombok.jar の在り処をフルパスで指定してあげる必要がありそうです。

```
$ java -cp /path/to/lombok.jar -jar lombok.jar delombok -f pretty src -d delombok-src
```

実行しているのはあくまで `java` コマンドなので、lombok.jar の在り処を PATH に追加しても意味がなくて、`java` コマンドに lombok.jar の場所を教える必要があります。

毎回入力するのが面倒な場合には、バッチファイルにまとめてもよいかもしれません。

Comment: ありがとうございます！

Comment: java -cp /usr/local/bin/lombok.jar -jar lombok.jar delombok -f pretty Person -d test3
と実行すると
Error: Unable to access jarfile lombok.jar
と怒られてしまいました。

javaコマンドではlombok.jarのパスは短縮できず、
java -jar /usr/local/bin/lombok.jar delombok -f pretty Person -d test2 

とフルパスで書くと覚えておきます。

Answer (score 1):

OS X 10.11 より [System Integrity Protection](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E3%82%B7%E3%82%B9%E3%83%86%E3%83%A0%E6%95%B4%E5%90%88%E6%80%A7%E4%BF%9D%E8%AD%B7) が導入されたので、一部ディレクトリは `sudo` からも保護されています。

ドラッグ＆ドロップであれば、`/usr/local/bin` ではどうですか？
または `mv lombok.jar /usr/local/bin/lombok.jar` でしょうか。

パスが通っているかはコマンドラインで `echo $PATH` で確認します。出力の中に `/usr/local/bin` があれば当該ディレクトリに配置したコマンドは認識されます（スクリプトならシェバンと実行権限の付与を忘れずに）。

Comment: ありがとうございます！

Comment: ただ以下のように実行したいファイルをdelombokしようとしたら
java -jar lombok.jar delombok -f pretty Person -d test2

次のように怒られました。
Error: Unable to access jarfile lombok.jar

なぜでしょうか？

Comment: java -jar /usr/local/bin/lombok.jar delombok -f pretty Person -d test2 
とすると実行できました。パスが通っているので/usr/local/bin/は短縮できると思ったのですが。
which lombok.jar　とすると /usr/local/bin/lombok.jarとちゃんと返ってきます